# can't launch springseed after update in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: updates

I have installed springseed on Ubuntu 13.04 & Worked fine for me until i don't update it , after update , i can't open it . When i click on it's icon on launcher nothing happens !

Answer (score 1):

I am Micheal Harker, one of the Springseed developers. Thanks for asking about this issue, I shall see what is going wrong in this version of Springseed, but for now you can fix the issue by doing the following:

- Start a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
- Enter the following command: `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/springseed.desktop`
- Find the line where it says `Exec=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/springseed /opt/springseed/springseed-bin`
- Replace that line with `Exec=/opt/springseed/springseed-bin`
- Save and try to boot the application.

Hopefully this should fix your issue, and in the next patch I should fix this issue completely. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: it was Exec=/opt/springseed/springseed-bin at first ! but program can't launch .(note : when the Version was 1.0 , program worked worth , but by updating to 1.1 crashed ) Can i downgrade (opposite of update) to launch it again ? and how ?